# What version of sqljdbc do I require?

Tags: java, sql-server, sql-server-2017, sqljdbc

I am running in to an issue with my application where I get the error.

The driver could not establish a secure connection to SQL Server by using Secure Sockets Layer (SSL) encryption. Error: "SQL Server returned an incomplete response."

I have looked and the only difference on my new server is version of SQL which leads me to think I have the wrong version of SQLJDBC4.jar

I have been looking for a version that works with Java version 1.6.0_27 and MS SQL Sever 2017

Does anyone have any suggestions of what version of this JAR I require?

Comment: I would recommend to forget using Java 1.6 quickly.

Comment: For SQL Server 2017 you need a minimum of JDBC 6.2. [Microsoft JDBC Driver for SQL Server Support Matrix - SQL Version Compatibility](https://learn.microsoft.com/en-us/sql/connect/jdbc/microsoft-jdbc-driver-for-sql-server-support-matrix?view=sql-server-2017#sql-version-compatibility)

Comment: Also, assuming that SQLJDBC4.jar means you're using Microsoft JDBC Driver 4.0 for SQL Server, then that has also been out of support for over 2 years (since march 6, 2017); see the link above for confirmation. You really need to update your tech.

Comment: @Larnu this is an old out dated application in a sector not willing to spend at the moment. I do not have the power to make decisions on advancing the stack - we are just trying to keep it ticking over for the time being.

Comment: Then you'll have to use an older version of SQL Server, @ThisIsLegend1016. JDBC 4.0 doesn't support SQL Server 2017. YOu either need to upgrade JDBC (to a minimum 6.2) or downgrade SQL Server (to a maximum of 2016).

Comment: It's also worth noting, however, that if you are using unsupported (and therefore unsecure) software, that you will be likely failing local compliance laws as well; unless you're in a very lax country.

Answer (score -1):

Please try to add the "sqljdbc42-0.jar" file to your build path.
Try the following link if it is maven project, else download the jar from any trusted url. 
https://mvnrepository.com/artifact/com.microsoft.sqlserver/sqljdbc42/6.0.8112

Comment: 4.2 doesn't support 2017 either. Only 6.2+ does (as linked in my comment).